# Dell Inspirion - are these the 3 pins and the jumper needed to reset CMOS?

Tags: motherboard, dell-inspiron, hardware-rec

And if so, why are there 2 of them?

[image: Red circled area]

[image]

Comment: Those do not appear to be the right jumpers. Can you add a full picture of your motherboard?

Comment: DrZoo - added a picture

Comment: What computer model is this? It's hard to zoom a bit an see anything. It becomes too pixelated.

Comment: Dr Zoo - Dell Inspirion 2305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the pins you have circled in the first picture does contain the correct jumper to reset the CMOS.

By looking at the service manual for the Inspirion One 2305, the reason there are two jumpers is because one jumper  is CLR_PSWD (clear password) jumper, and the other is the CLR_CMOS (CMOS Jumper).

To reset the CMOS, you'll want to turn off your PC and unplug the power cord. Move the jumper on board component 18, which is the jumper furthest to the right in your original picture with the red circle. Move the jumper from pins 3 and 2, to 1 and 2 for 5-10 seconds. Then put the jumper back on pins 3 and 2. You can then plug in your PC and turn it back on.

Here is the motherboard manual that shows the system board components.

[image]

Here is the pinout from the manual.
[image]

Comment: There are four pins there, do the instructions change?

Comment: There's four? The manual says and shows only three. I added another picture from the manual.

Comment: This is strange indeed, I guess I shall try both 3-4 and 2-3 But notice the manual is 2310 instead of 2305. I will search it up.

Comment: Yes it appears the one above is 2305, and the one below is a different one, but both display only three.

Comment: Yeah the only difference between 2305 and 2310 is the location of the jumper.

Comment: Would you say that simply removing the jumper is going to clear the data, or does it need to be reconnected to these other ones in order for that to happen?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think moving the jumper shorts something and causes it to reset.

Comment: @Orangeball3 did you have any luck?

Comment: Yes it worked out, from 1-2 to 2-3. I didn't try that last one.